# How to create kick up dust behind tires in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I making a Desert type car game. I want to add functionality like when my car hits ground. Dust particles fly behind my car tires and when my car is in air, particles disappear. Thank you.

Comment: You want to attach a particle emitter to each wheel and turn it off when the wheel elaves contat with the ground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add collider and rigidbody to track and you car wheel objects and then check that if car is colliding with track then on the particle system else off it. You can use [on collision stay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html).